# Conversion operator template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization

Here's a largely academic exercise in understanding conversion operators, templates and template specializations.  The conversion operator template in the following code works for `int`, `float`, and `double`, but fails when used with `std::string`... sort of.  I've created a specialization of the conversion to `std::string`, which works when used with initialization `std::string s = a;`, but fails when used with a cast `static_cast<std::string>(a)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class MyClass {
     int y;
public:
    MyClass(int v) : y(v) {}
    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return y; };
};

template<>
MyClass::operator std::string() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << y << " bottles of beer.";
    return ss.str();
}

int main () {
    MyClass a(99);
    int i    = a;
    float f  = a;
    double d = a;
    std::string s = a;

    std::cerr << static_cast<int>(a) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << static_cast<float>(a) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << static_cast<double>(a) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << static_cast<std::string>(a) << std::endl; // Compiler error
}
```

The above code generates a compiler error in g++ and icc, both complaining that no user-defined conversion is suitable for converting a `MyClass` instance to a `std::string` on the `static_cast` (C-style casts behave the same).

If I replace the above code with explicit, non-template versions of the conversion operator, everything is happy:

```
class MyClass {
    int y;
public:
    MyClass(int v) : y(v) {}
    operator double() {return y;}
    operator float()  {return y;}
    operator int()    {return y;}
    operator std::string() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << y << " bottles of beer.";
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

What is wrong with my template specialization for `std::string`?  Why does it work for initialization but not casting?

Update:

After some template wizardry by @luc-danton (meta-programming tricks I'd never seen before), I have the following code working in g++ 4.4.5 after enabling experimental C++0x extensions.  Aside from the horror of what is being done here, requiring experimental compiler options is reason enough alone to **not** do this.  Regardless, this is hopefully as educational for others as it was for me:

```
class MyClass {
    int y;
public:
    MyClass(int v) : y(v) {}

    operator std::string() { return "nobody"; }

    template <
        typename T
        , typename Decayed = typename std::decay<T>::type
        , typename NotUsed = typename std::enable_if<
            !std::is_same<const char*, Decayed>::value &&
            !std::is_same<std::allocator<char>, Decayed>::value &&
            !std::is_same<std::initializer_list<char>, Decayed>::value
          >::type
    >
    operator T() { return y; }
};
```

This apparently forces the compiler to choose the conversion `operator std::string()` for `std::string`, which gets past whatever ambiguity the compiler was encountering.

Comment: maybe related, though I'm not sure how exactly: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @sth: The linked article talks about template specializations and the order of resolution.  To see if that was the problem I'm running into (seems plausible) I removed my specialization for std::string.  Unfortunately, the cast results in the *same* compiler error.  If it was a different error, I'd say it could be related.  Alas it doesn't seem so.

Comment: That's the point of the article: specializations *do not* help with overload resolution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reproduce the problem by just using

```
std::string t(a);
```

Combined with the actual error from GCC (`error: call of overloaded 'basic_string(MyClass&)' is ambiguous`) we have strong clues as to what may be happening: there is one preferred conversion sequence in the case of *copy initialization* (`std::string s = a;`), and in the case of *direct initialization* (`std::string t(a);` and `static_cast`) there are at least two sequences where one of them can't be preferred over the other.

Looking at all the `std::basic_string` explicit constructors taking one argument (the only ones that would be considered during direct initialization but not copy initialization), we find `explicit basic_string(const Allocator& a = Allocator());` which is in fact the only explicit constructor.

Unfortunately I can't do much beyond that diagnostic: I can't think of a trick to discover is `operator std::allocator<char>` is instantiated or not (I tried SFINAE and `operator std::allocator<char>() = delete;`, to no success), and I know too little about function template specializations, overload resolution and library requirements to know if the behaviour of GCC is conforming or not.

Since you say the exercise is academic, I will spare you the usual diatribe how non-explicit conversion operators are not a good idea. I think your code is a good enough example as to why anyway :)

---

I got SFINAE to work. If the operator is declared as:

```
template <
    typename T
    , typename Decayed = typename std::decay<T>::type
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<
            const char*
            , Decayed
        >::value
        && !std::is_same<
            std::allocator<char>
            , Decayed
        >::value
        && !std::is_same<
            std::initializer_list<char>
            , Decayed
        >::value
    >::type
>
operator T();
```

Then there is no ambiguity and the code will compile, the specialization for `std::string` will be picked and the resulting program will behave as desired. I still don't have an explanation as to why copy initialization is fine.

Comment: Why is copy-initialization well-defined, though? `std::string` also has a non-explicit one-argument constructor from `const char *` -- is the copy constructor preferred over a conversion constructor?

Comment: @KerrekSB As I said, I don't know much about overload resolution. I only focused on the *differences* between `std::string s = a;` and `std::string t(a);`. (Also the error message of GCC was very explicit about what was happening in the direct initialization case.) Check the rules -- I expect that for a conversion from U to T, `U -> T` via `U::operator T` is preferred over `U -> const char* -> T` (via `U::operator const char*` then `T(const char*)`) or some such.

Comment: Using the non-templatized version, `cerr << std::string(a) << endl;` works as well in both g++ and icc.  That seems like the most difficult syntax to decipher, but the compilers eat it up happily.  I previously chased down the same path you've listed here, including using explicit expansion of the std::string type to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`, but never got anywhere.  What is confusing the compilers is beyond me (and apparently the compiler too).

Comment: @Nathan The second case (without a conversion operator template) might work because not making the operator a template might make it preferred. In the first case, specializing `operator T` won't help with overload resolution however (I recommend `sth`'s link in your comments). In other words, just because you can provide the same *functionality* with several overloads as with writing a template (including any or no specialization) doesn't mean the language rules are the same.

Comment: @Nathan: `std::string(a)` always works because it invokes the conversion operator explicitly. You can say `cout << string(a)` if you like. But `string b(a);` does not work (while `string b(string(a));` does).

Comment: @KerrekSB Surprisingly, with g++ and icc, `string b(a);` *does* work (using non-templatized form of class).

Comment: @Nathan: The non-templated version isn't under discussion here I think. The problem is one of ambiguous argument deductions, so only the templated version is affected.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` here is equivalent of doing `std::string(a)`.

Note that `std::string s = std::string(a);` doesn't compile either. My guess is, there are plenty of overloads for the constructor, and the template version can convert `a` to many suitable types.

On the other hand, with a fixed list of conversions, only one of those matches exactly a type that the string's constructor accepts.

To test this, add a conversion to `const char*` - the non-templated version should start failing at the same place.

(Now the question is why `std::string s = a;` works. Subtle differences between that and `std::string s = std::string(a);` are only known to gods.)