# Different casting operators used by different compilers

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

The following C++ program compiles without warnings in all compilers I have tried (gcc 4.6.3, llvm 3.0, icc 13.1.1, SolarisStudio 12.1/12.3):

```
struct CClass
{
  template<class T>
  operator T() const { return 1; }

  operator int() const { return 2; }
};

int main(void)
{
  CClass x;
  return static_cast<char>(x);
}
```

*However, all but the SolarisStudio compilers return 2, SolarisStudio (either version) returns 1, which I would consider the most logical result.*

Using `return x.operator char();` results in all compilers returning 1.

Obviously, since figuring this out, I have been using the latter notation. However, I would like to know which of compilers is correct and why. (One would think that majority rules, but this still doesn't explain the *why*.)

This question seems to be related to the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116654/function-template-with-an-operator), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892774/conversion-operator-overloading-ambiguity-compilers-differ), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741531/conversion-operator-template-specialization), but these "only" give solutions to problems, no explanations (that I was able to apply to my particular problem anyway).

Note that adding an additional overloaded casting operator, say `operator float() const { return 3; }` results in all compilers except SolarisStudio complaining about ambiguity.

Comment: Just tested in my compiler, G++ 4.8.0, and it returns 1.

Comment: G++ 4.7.2 also returns 1. And with `operator float()`, there is no complaint about any ambiguity.

Comment: g++ returns one starting from 4.7 http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: this is terrible code. Avoid general (non-specialised or not-restricted [via `std::enable_if<>` for example]) template conversion operators, as these may lead to unwanted and un-foreseen conversions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The first (template) overload should be picked**.

Paragraph 13.3.3/1 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> [...] a viable function `F1` is defined to be a **better function than another viable function**
>   `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> — for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, if not that,
>
> — **the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion** (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) **and the
>   standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type** (i.e., the type of the
>   entity being initialized) **is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>   the return type of `F2` to the destination type**. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>     A();
>     operator int();
>     operator double();
> } a;
> int i = a; // a.operator int() followed by no conversion
>            // is better than a.operator double() followed by
>            // a conversion to int
> float x = a; // ambiguous: both possibilities require conversions,
>              // and neither is better than the other
> ```
>
> —*end example* ] or, **if not that**,
>
> — `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
>
> [...]

As you can see the, fact that the first conversion operator is a template only becomes relevant when the standard conversion sequence from its return type (`char`, in this case) to the destination type (`char`, in this case) is **not** better than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of the non-template overload (`int`, in this case) to the destination type (`char`, in this case).

However, a standard conversion from `char` to `char` is an *Exact Match*, while a standard conversion from `int` to `char` is not. Therefore, the third item of § 13.3.3/1 does not apply, and the second item does.

This means that **the first (template) overload should be picked**.

Comment: Not really. It says that a template **specialization** will be picked over that. But in the op's case there's no specialization. The compiler won't even start to create a template, because it already found a matching non-template cast that it can use. Templates are only created if they are called explicitly, or there's no other matching overload. There's no reason for the compiler to start "guessing" at a matching template

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: No, that's just not true. It won't instantiate the template, but it will perform template argument deduction and see if the template is a viable candidate for overload resolution. If that turns out to be the *best* viable candidate, it will pick it and instantiate it

Answer (score 5):

The first is an exact match, the second requires a conversion. Exact matches have priority over conversions.

Those other questions you linked are mostly unrelated to yours.

Some advice: don't use template conversion operators. Name it `convert_to` instead.

Comment: +1 one for warning about template conversion operators. Perhaps you could add some explanation why this is dangerous.